# Facebook Credits with C# SDK

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

UPDATE
I have since been able to get the popup working. I removed/commented out unnecessary code I was using below. For some strange reason I had to switch to an aspx from my ashx. Just make sure all of the variables you lookup in your database exist :)

I'm having some issues implementing facebook credits into my facebook app. I'm using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) and I'm sure my javascript is kosher. I found [this](http://www.m-webs.com/blog_facebookcredits.html) blog to be helpful, but I am getting an AppInvalidDecodedResponse error back from facebook in my javascript callback. I am just initially trying to get the 'buy' popup to display. Here is my ashx callback specified in the app settings:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string order_id = Request.Form["order_id"];
    string method = Request.Form["method"];        
    string order_info = Request.Form["order_info"];


    FacebookBuyItem theItem = new FacebookBuyItem();
    theItem.title = "item not found";
    theItem.price = "1";
    theItem.image_url = Utilities.GlobalSettings["WebDomain"];
    theItem.product_url = Utilities.GlobalSettings["WebDomain"];
    theItem.description = "item not found";

    if (method == "payments_get_items")
    {

        //order_info = (string)data["order_info"];
        //order_info = order_info.Substring(1, (order_info.Length - 2));
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(Utilities.PluginSettings["SQL Database"]["ConnectionString"]);
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.GetItem";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(order_info);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                theItem.title = dr["ItemName"].ToString();
                theItem.price = dr["FacebookCreditCost"].ToString();
                theItem.image_url = dr["ThumbPath"].ToString();
                theItem.product_url = dr["ThumbPath"].ToString();
                theItem.description = dr["Description"].ToString();
            }
            dr.Close();

            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
    //Utilities.Dump(order_info, order_id, method);
    var res = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    res["method"] = method;
    //res["order_id"] = order_id;
    res["content"] = new object[] { theItem };


    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string ob = jss.Serialize(res);
    //ob = ob.Replace("#$", @"\/");
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Response.Write(ob);
    Response.End(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an engineer at Facebook and can hopefully help out here. Invalid decoded response means that the callback is not providing the necessary and properly formatted item information back to facebook during the `payments_get_items` call. The good news is, facebook is getting *something* from your callback, just not the right *something*. I'm not experienced with c# but at first, I would try hard coding your item name, price, etc like I did below and check if it works as expected.

```
        theItem.title = 'BFF Locket';
        theItem.price = 1;
        theItem.image_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/21.png';
        theItem.product_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/21.png';
        theItem.description = 'This is a BFF Locket...';
```

Let me know if you're still having issues and I can look into this further.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm still having issues. Primarily, it's difficult to tell if it is actually being called. In my callback ashx, I am recording an entry into the database regardless of control flow(at the top,first thing we do). When calling manually, I see the record get dumped to the database, but when called through our app, we get the response of an invalid decoding, but nothing gets put into the database as if it was never called. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I reviewed the FB credits api under application callbacks and attempted to mirror my return after the example: `code`{"content":[{"title":"[Test Mode] Unicorn","description":"[Test Mode] Own your own mythical beast!","price":2,"image_url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/images\/gifts\/21.png","product_url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/images\/gifts\/21.png"}],"method":"payments_get_items"} 
I changed the 'res' object to omit the 'order_id' part and I removed the ob.replace mess. From there I was able to get the sample popup and then go about debugging the errors in the database lookup code. Thanks

Comment: Great to hear, let me know I can further assist.